# ArcGIS Server WFS does not render custom style in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers, symbology, wfs

When I load my WFS into OpenLayers 4 it does not use the custom style which I've specified in ArcGIS Server. The points appear in the default OL style (white transparent fill with a blue outline).

I remember that when I used GeoServer the styles specified in the server would automatically appear in OL. So I expected it to be the same way with ArcGIS Server, but I guess that is not the case. I've added `styles=default&` in the WFS URL but with no success.

The JS I'm using to load the WFS:

```
SamF2016source = new ol.source.Vector({
format: new ol.format.WFS(),
loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'https://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&typeName=SamF2016&version=1.1.0&styles=default&SRSname=EPSG:3857&outputFormat=gml3';
    // Use fetch, more simple & modern instead of XMLHttpRequest
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function (text) {
        var features = SamF2016source.getFormat().readFeatures(text);
        // Add parsed features to vectorSource
        SamF2016source.addFeatures(features);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    })
}
});

SamF2016 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: SamF2016source,
    setZIndex: 1005,
    title: 'SamF2016',
    visible: false,
});
```

In the GetCapabilities of the server the style is specified as so (bottom part of the GML):

```
Layer queryable="1">
<Name>1</Name>
<Title>
<![CDATA[ SamF2013 ]]>
</Title>
<Abstract>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:28992</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>4.211658</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>6.025627</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>51.244639</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>51.815840</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="4.211658" miny="51.244639" maxx="6.025627" maxy="51.815840"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="51.244639" miny="4.211658" maxx="51.815840" maxy="6.025627"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:28992" minx="73913.494800" miny="362246.413600" maxx="198987.600000" maxy="425141.200000"/>
<Style>
<Name>default</Name>
<Title>1</Title>
<LegendURL width="130" height="928">
<Format>image/png</Format>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WmsServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=1" xlink:type="simple"/>
</LegendURL>
</Style>
</Layer>
```

When GetLegendGraphic is called the right symbology returns:
http://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WmsServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=1

With a GetMap request the right symbology also returns (BBOX is a bit off but you get the idea):
https://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.0&layers=1&styles=default&srs=EPSG:28992&bbox=-73913.494800,362246.413600,198987.600000,425141.200000&&width=780&height=330&format=image%2Fpng

What code do I need to add/adjust so that the points in my OL map appear like the symbology in the GetLegendGraphic and GetMap requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WFS don't give any rendered style, it's for you to apply.  This is what any WFS does ~ gives you vector data.

WMS give an image where you give a style (using SLD) or you accept the default style.

The GetCapabilities you give is showing you the [capabilities of the WMS](https://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&), the WFS has a [different GetCapabilities](https://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&) response, and different capabilities.

For the FeatureType that you are requesting has the following capabilities, there are no styles here:

```
<FeatureType>
    <Name>fauna:SamF2016</Name>
    <Title>SamF2016</Title>
    <DefaultCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:28992</DefaultCRS>
    <OtherSRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326</OtherSRS>
    <OutputFormats>
        <Format>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</Format>
    </OutputFormats>
    <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
        <ows:LowerCorner>4.2697569340901396 51.221271739696967</ows:LowerCorner>
        <ows:UpperCorner>6.029130352568183 51.822105829878616</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</FeatureType>
```

Note the responses of the GetCapabilities requests is not GML its `text/xml`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So if I understand correctly it is not that easy to create a custom style like mine for a WFS? Having various amounts of fieldnames en colors.

Comment: You can't (AFAIK ~ would depend on the output formats supplied) create a style for a WFS, (you can't have the server apply a style that you request with the data), you can only style the data you receive from a WFS, that is apply the style in your client whether it be OpenLayers or ArcGIS or QGIS.  Certainly with this service which only gives GML, you can't add a style.  In the future with the support of vector tiles it might be a possibility.